# How do I pass onDateSet method to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a method in my Activity:

```
// activity.class
private void setDate(int year) {
    view.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year));

}
```

I need this to be called when a `DatePickerDialog`'s `OnDateSetListener` is called:

```
// DatePickerDialogFragment.class
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener l = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(int year) {
            <activity>.setDate(year)
        }
    }
}
```

The `<activity>` (or however I'm suppsed to do this) contains a reference to the view that needs to be set. How do I access it inside the `DialogFragment`?

I tried doing something like this:

```
//activity.class
DatePickerDialogFragment frag = new DatePickerDialogFragment(this);
```

But how do I access the method of the activity in the `DatePickerDialogFragment` class file?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an interface and make activity implement it:

```
interface DataSetter {
 void setDate(int year);
}

 YourActivity extends Activity implements DataSetter {

    public void setDate(int year) {
      textView.setText(year+"");
    }
}
```

2.1)

```
@Override
        public void onDateSet(int year) {
            Activity activity= getActivity();
            if (activity != null && activity instanceof DataSetter) {                       
            (DataSetter)activity.setDate(year)
        }
     }
```

2.2) or bind activity to a field in onAttach and use it afterwards.

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete example? I do not follow how this approach allows me to inject a view dependent method from my activity to a helper class.

Comment: Which step you do not understand? Activity shows the dialog so the dialog will hold the inner reference to the activity (getActivity()). By implementing some interface it is possible to make this activity's method invocation without "ugly" casting to Activity implementation itself

Comment: This approach i believe is unnecessarily verbose. I tried making a base `DatePickerActivity` class that has a `setDate()` method and then casting the current `getActivity()` to `DatePickerActivity` but this, I believe, could cause performance issues. Thoughts?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html this is a recommended way of communication between activity and fragments. As for perfomance - casting is fast in modern java-machine implementation. Class casting is not reusable friendly as interface one.